# youtube-analytics-api pagination stopping

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics, youtube-analytics-api

I am trying to paginate thru data using the start-index parameter, I am incrementing the start-index value in a looping construct, it works fine for 1st and 2nd loop, but fails on 3 loop every time (I know there are more videos).

Am I paginating wrong?

> HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?sort=-views&max-results=99&dimensions=video&start-date=2014-05-29&start-index=199&ids=channel%3D%3DUCNHqb1IRxQ5WBsWtO53JL2g&metrics=views%2Ccomments%2Clikes%2Cdislikes%2CvideosAddedToPlaylists%2CvideosRemovedFromPlaylists%2Cshares%2CfavoritesAdded%2CfavoritesRemoved%2CestimatedMinutesWatched%2CaverageViewDuration%2CaverageViewPercentage%2CannotationClickThroughRate%2CannotationCloseRate%2CannotationImpressions%2CannotationClickableImpressions%2CannotationClosableImpressions%2CannotationClicks%2CannotationCloses%2CsubscribersGained%2CsubscribersLost&alt=json&end-date=2015-10-07
>
> returned "The query is not supported. Check the documentation at https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/available_reports for a list of supported queries."

Comment: Are you able to get a similar issue with any other queries?

Comment: I am looping over 16 channels, 3 of the channels are giving me trouble with incomplete results, 2 are failing on the use of start_index 199 and 1 channel is only returning 10 and there are thousands of videos.  So same query with slightly different parameters

Comment: let me add I am a complete newbie to API, oauth2, scopes, youtube content/channel management, quota's etc., it could be something I just don't understand.  On the 2 that fail at start_index 199, the error code and message are 401 Login Required, not quite sure what that means, how am I able to retrieve any results if not already logged in?

Comment: turns out there is an "undocumented feature" that limits this API at start_index 199.  This was a painful process taking over 3 weeks to get a response and invalidated my initial development.